# How do I copy a CSV file into postgresql on Manjaro (Permision Denied Issue)?

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, manjaro

I am running Manjaro Linux and trying to get familiar with PostgresSQL. I am attempting to import a csv file located at `/home/antonnym/Downloads/persons.csv` into a table on postgresql.

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
          id SERIAL, 
          first_name VARCHAR(50), 
          last_name VARCHAR(50), 
          dob DATE, 
          email VARCHAR(255), 
          PRIMARY KEY (id) 
);

\copy persons from '/home/antonnym/Downloads/persons.csv' delimiter ',' csv header;
```

I'm getting the error `/home/antonnym/Downloads/persons.csv: Permission denied`.

I'm using psql (PostgreSQL) 13.4 on Manjaro 21.2. How do I get the correct permission settings?

Answer (score 0):

Try run this command in Linux terminal:

```
chmod 777 /home/antonnym/Downloads/persons.csv
```